# Spectrum of hermitian matrix is symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The matrix $$T = \begin{pmatrix} m & s \\ \overline{s} & -m \end{pmatrix}$$
with $m \in \mathbb R$ and $s \in \mathbb C$
has eigenvalues $\pm \lambda.$ This one can see by diagonlizing this matrix explicitly.

However, does there exist a unitary matrix $U$ such that

$$U T U^* = -T?$$

If $m$ is zero, then we can just take $U = \begin{pmatrix} 1  & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}.$

Comment: that $T$ isn't symmetric

Comment: no, I am saying the spectrum is symmetric with respect to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - it is a traceless hermitian matrix.  It can be diagonalized with real eigenvalues by $Q^*TQ=D$

now use the only $2\times 2$ permutation matrix $P$ that isn't the identity (note $P=P^*$).

$P^*Q^*TQP = P^*DP= -D = - Q^*TQ$
Finally left multiply by $Q$ and right multiply by $Q^*$

$U^*TU=\big(QPQ^*\big)^*T\big(QPQ^*\big) =\big(QP^*Q^*\big)T\big(QPQ^*\big) = - Q\big(Q^*TQ\big)Q^*= -T$